# IBM RAD 7.5 ... why does it take WebSphere so long to start / publish / republish / debug?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad-7.5

I'm developing an EAR/WAR application with IBM RAD 7.5 and WebSphere 7.

When I run my app on WebSphere 7 within "eclispe", it take *forever* for WebSphere to start in "Run" mode (2 or 3 minutes).  Much longer to start in "Debug" mode (5 to 10 minutes).

I have 'publish automatically' turned off, so I republish manually, and that too take a long long time.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there anyway to speed thing up?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: What do you mean by 'forever'? Your question is far too broad... furthermore the product is fairly complex. Just open a ticket with IBM (in my experience it taks approx 30 seconds to start WebSphere in RAD 7.x).

Comment: "Forever" means 2 or 3 minutes in RUN mode, 5 or 10 minutes in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you're hitting memory limits on your system and perhaps doing a lot of swapping. My WebSphere 6.1 under RAD 8 seems to start in an amount of time consistent with WebSphere by itself.

Comment: I'm on a Windows XP machine, System Properties says it's 3.13GHz, 2.99GB RAM (I'm guessing the RAM number is a Windows XP limitation).  Is there anyway to allow IBM RAD or WebSphere access to more memory, or see how much memory they are limited to?

Comment: No way to allow RAD/WAS access to more RAM than XP will let you use. (I'm on 64-bit Windows 7 with 8G of RAM). You can look at the Windows Task Manager to see how much memory the Eclipse and WAS processes are using (although they'll be java.exe and/or javaw.exe) and the Peformace tab to see what Windows' memory state is.

Comment: I added `-vmargs -Xmx1024M` to the RAD launcher icon and that helped things a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `metadata-complete="true"` in your web.xml   I experienced significant improvements doing this.

Comment: This is very intersting news, you know of any main switch to force all web archives and ejbs to become metadata-complete="true"? We have hundreds of wars and EJBs and are not using any servlet 3.0 features yet. Would be interesting to quickly try if that reduces publishing times, which currently is minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the Heap for the test environment.

Personally build automatically and auto-publish should be turned off, You run the publish as and when you need it.

This one is still a good reference
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113606723/radtipsv754.pdf?version=1

Sometimes when it takes 5-10 to publish in debug mode, i either revert to export and install via the admin console or use wsadmin scripts to install the application.

Also turn on the heap config for RAD (one of the preference allows you to show this). You might be able to make some inferences if RAD is hitting into memory issues.

HTH

Manglu